# Trying to add Qooxdoo widgets in html page

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

As a proof of concept I would like to show the some **Qooxdoo** widgets (which i find pretty nice) in a very simple index.html file.

Here I try to show a button :

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5/framework/q-3.5.min.js"></script>


    <script>

        var button = new qx.ui.form.Button("Hello...");
        this.getRoot().add(button, {left: 30, top: 20});

    </script>

</head>
```

If I run the above I get this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: qx is not defined

Is my library link correct? Or is it even possible to link qooxdoo javascript in a HTML file? We already have a large established javascript application, and we would like to just drop in qooxdoo widgets that we like. Not sure if that is possible though.

Comment: So.... what is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to show a table in index.html. I have put the javascript in the script tags, but i am not sure what i need to import.

Comment: can you show some code you have tried ?

Comment: You will need to include the qooxdoo js file, you can copy/paste the code into `<script>` tags in your index.html file if you want it to be contained in a single file.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5/framework/q-3.5.min.js"></script>`

Comment: nope. tried that. it wont work for my table

Answer (score 1):

You are including the qx.Website library and try to use qx.Desktop widgets. That ain't gonna work. Either you choose qx.Desktop and use the inline app approach [1] or you use the qx.Website widgets [2].

[1] http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/development/skeletons.html#inline

[2] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/website-api/index.html#Accordion

Comment: so I have to run this PY file like this? create-application.py --name=custom --type=inline ? For some reason my WinZIP program tries to open the file after i hit return.